# Proper pattern to define methods of properties in a javascript "class"

Tags: javascript, class, oop, scope, this

I am trying to make a Person class with a Person.energy property that contains a Person.energy.value number and a Person.energy.rest function that restores the Person.energy.value.

When I define Person.energy, I can set properties based on the this.ability property. But when I try to update properties in a method, I lose the scope that grants access to this.ability. I've crafted an example to explain what I mean...

In the definition for Person.energy below, the this.ability variable is accessed to set the Person.energy.initial and .value variables. This seems to work fine since I can console.log the variables after the object is created. However, when I try to access the same this.ability variable as part of the Person.energy.rest function, it is undefined. This seems to be a scope issue.

I understand that I am not doing a good job of organizing my class methods and properties but I don't know what the proper way to do it is. **What is a good javascript class pattern to define methods of properties that can still access the sibling properties of the parent?**

**== Code ==**

```
function Person() {
    this.init = function() {
        //later: more complex var assignment
        var talent = 0.5;
        var skill = 0.5;
        return [talent, skill];
    };
    [this.talent, this.skill] = this.init();
    this.calculate();
    return this;
}

Person.prototype.calculate = function() {
    this.ability = this.talent * this.skill;
    this.energy = {
        initial: this.ability * 100,
        value: this.ability * 100
    };
    this.energy.rest = function() {
        console.log(this.ability, " <--- this.ability out of scope");
        var amount = this.ability * Math.random();
        this.value = this.value + amount;
    };
};

p = new Person();
console.log(p.energy.value, " <--  calculated using this.ability");
p.energy.rest();
```

**== Console.log ==**

```
25   <--  calculated using this.ability
undefined  <--- this.ability out of scope
```

Comment: Calling something like `p.energy.rest()` will end up calling the `rest()` method with `this` set to `p.energy` and there is no direct way to make it be `p`.  The likely solution to your problem is to NOT nest methods into an extra object.  Methods should be attached to the object that they want the `this` pointer of.  You can put a `parent` reference into `p.energy` that points to `p` if you must and then you can use `this.parent` to get the `p` object from `p.energy.rest()`, but usually the better solution is to just get rid of the nested object.

Comment: I discovered a workaround. Since p.energy.initial is equal to this.ability * 100, I can use this.initial/100 instead of this.ability within the p.energy.rest function and it works perfectly. However, your explanation of the proper way is highly valued. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Person.prototype.calculate = function() {
    var oPerson = this;//will be referring to person object which will have scope across this function.
    this.ability = this.talent * this.skill;
    this.energy = {
        initial: this.ability * 100,
        value: this.ability * 100
    };
    this.energy.rest = function() {
        console.log(oPerson.ability, " <--- this.ability out of scope");
        var amount = oPerson.ability * Math.random();
        this.value = this.value + amount;
    };
};
```

Comment: This is a working solution that resolves the scope issue. Moreover, it shows explicitly how to define a scoped variable that is treated as global by the property's method. Thank you. In the long run, I think @jfriend00 is right that it's best to define the methods without nesting them.